# Unicode glyph not displayed in Qt

Tags: qt, unicode, pyqt4

I want to display the [glyph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0985/index.htm) for the Unicode code-point `0x00985` in `Qt`, using the font `Arial Unicode MS`. Using `PyQt4`, I wrote this:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

font = QFont('Arial Unicode MS')
font.setPointSize(100)
print QFontInfo(font).family()
print QFontMetrics(font).inFont(QChar(0x00985))

label = QLabel(QChar(0x00985))
label.setFont(font)
label.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the glyph is not shown on the label; there is a white box instead. Indeed, the second print-statement returns `False`, showing that `Qt` cannot find the glyph. If the code-point `0x00985` is replaced with code-point `0x00A85`, then there is a nice rendering of the [appropriate glyph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0a85/index.htm).

Why cannot the glyph for the code-point `0x00985` be drawn?

#### Font installation

The first print-statement shows that the selected font really is `Arial Unicode MS`. The `Fonts` dialog in `Windows 10` shows that the font `Arial Unicode MS Regular` is installed. The font is stored in file `ARIALUNI.TTF`. Opening this file in [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) shows that the glyph for the Unicode code-point `0x00985` is present in the font, contrary to what `Qt` reports.

#### Glyph existence

According to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0985/fontsupport.htm), `Arial Unicode MS` font contains a glyph for the Unicode code-point `0x00985`. You can see the glyph in action [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0985/index.htm). The existence is verified by using the [full Unicode Input Utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8). In `Chrome`, inspecting the element containing the glyph via developer tools shows that `Arial Unicode MS` is used to render the glyph.

Edit: Changed print-statement to use `QFontInfo`.

#### Fallback behavior

Suppose you install the `FreeSans` font. Change the font in the script to `FreeSans`. Run the program; it works. Change the font in the script back to `Arial Unicode MS`; it still works. However, using `FontForge`, and comparing the glyphs, it can be seen that the displayed glyph is from `FreeSans`. Further verification is obtained by uninstalling `FreeSans`, in which case `Arial Unicode MS` again does not work.

Comment: The print statement will show the name of the font that was *requested*, which is not necessarily the same as the font used to draw the text. To get the actual font used, you need to use [QFontInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontinfo.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro I changed to use QFontInfo, but the result is unfortunately the same (edited the text).

Comment: Have you tried using another font that has support for that character? I tested your script on Linux using the DejuVu Sans font, and Qt has no problem rendering that character.

Comment: @ekhumoro FreeSans works. Are you sure you tested on DejaVu Sans? According to FontForge, the glyph is not present in DejaVu Sans. Maybe there are differing versions of the font?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DejaVu Sans, but that doesn't necessarily mean the glyph is taken from that font, as you've already discovered. The point of my previous comment was simply to confirm that Qt is able to render the character correctly.